# How cast C++ class to intrinsic type

Tags: c++, casting, intrinsics

Basic C++ class question:

I have simple code currently that looks like something like this:

```
typedef int sType;
int array[100];

int test(sType s)
{
  return array[ (int)s ];
}
```

What I want, is to convert "sType" to a class, such that the "return array[ (int)s ]" line does not need to be changed. e.g. (pseudocode)

```
class sType
{
  public:
    int castInt()
    {
      return val;
    }
    int val;
}


int array[100];    
int test(sType s)
{
  return array[ (int)s ];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For bonus points, how do I make sure "s = 5;" works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class sType
{
public:
    operator int() const { return val; }

private:
    int val;
};
```

Comment: Nice idea with the private but you've left him no way to set it

Comment: @Rup: I assume OP knows what a constructor is :)

Comment: By the way, C++0x allows the conversion function (`operator int()`) to be marked "explicit", so that the cast `(int)s` is required. As it stands, you can write just `array[s]`, but sometimes it's not desirable to allow that, for the same reason that sometimes you want to mark single-arg constructors explicit.

Comment: @Steve: good to know. I try to avoid conversion functions usually, because of the implicit semantics.

Answer (score 6):

```
class sType
{
  public:
    operator int() const
    {
      return val;
    }
    int val;
};
```

To make s = 5 work, provide  a constructor that takes an int:

```
class sType
{
  public:

    sType (int n ) : val( n ) {
    }

    operator int() const
    {
      return val;
    }
    int val;
};
```

The compiler will then use that constructor whenever it need to convert an sType to an int.