# C++ primitive array accessing by class

Tags: c++, class, indexing

I want to access a primitive type array using a class.
I'm using Visual C++ 2013

```
class CInt
{
public:
    CInt() { val_ = 0; }
    CInt(int x) { val_ = x; }

private:
    int val_;
};

int arr[2];
CInt index;

arr[index] = 2; // ERROR!
```

I tried to overload size_t() operator but still doesn't work.
Is something like that possible in C++/C++11?

Comment: Do you wantro use your class object as an index? Why?

Comment: What is the purpose behind the `CInt` class? What is the problem it is supposed to solve?

Comment: As for your problem *how* did you implement the `int` or `size_t` operators? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? Also when adding the MCVE to your question, include the possible errors you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How cast C++ class to intrinsic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469894/how-cast-c-class-to-intrinsic-type).  Can't really tell though since you don't provide a [mcve]

Comment: What does `arr[index]` do?

Comment: Should we guess at the error? And what does "doesn't work" mean? Come on man

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have an error, not because of your class, but where you are doing the array assignment. You must do the array assignment within a function: (this should work, assuming you overloaded the conversion operator correctly)

```
arr[index] = 2; // ERROR! <-- you can't do this outside a function 

int main() {
    arr[index] = 2; // <-- must be within a function
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you do the overloading of the size_t() operator? The following works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

class CInt
{
public:
    CInt() { val_ = 0; }
    CInt(int x) { val_ = x; }

    operator size_t() const { return val_; }

private:
    int val_;
};

int main() {
    int arr[2];
    CInt index;

    arr[index] = 2;

    // output: 2
    std::cout << arr[index] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok my mistake then! also sorry for incomplete question / error reporting.