# Default return of class instance without member function

Tags: c++, class, return, default

Is it possible to make a class return a particular member variable by default when the object is used somewhere(without using a getter member function)?

If I have this class:

```
class A{
    public: 
       A(int nr) : number(nr){};
       ~A();
       int getNr(){ return this->number };
       int number;
};
```

To set and get its number later in the program, I can do this:

```
int main(){
    A thing(23);
    std::cout<<"Your number is: "<<thing.getNr();
    return 0;
}
```

But what I would like to do is this:

```
std::cout<<"Your number is: "<<thing;
```

And get the exact same result, make it return the member variable "*number*" by default. Can this be done/set somehow?

I know somebody might be thinking "*Why not just use integers as they are for that?*" - I'm making a class which should be able to "*turn into*" any type and then act like the assigned type, it would be nice if I could make it act like ints, doubles, strings in that regard too later.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469894/how-cast-c-class-to-intrinsic-type

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion have a look at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific example invokes the `<<` [stream insertion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion) on an `A`. This operator [can be overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public: 
        A(int nr) : number(nr) { }
        ~A() { }
        int getNr() const { return this->number; }
        int number;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
    os << a.getNr();
    return os;
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    A a(42);
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // prints 42
}
```

Note here I have made some other minor fixes to your code (fixed a missing `;` and removed some unnecessary ones; added `const` to `getNr()`).

For other situations, such as passing arguments of type `A` to functions that accept parameters of a different type, you can define [user-defined conversion operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) that are called by the compiler to convert an `A` to a different type. For example:

```
void doSomething(int x) {
    // ...
}

class A{
    public: 
        A(int nr) : number(nr){}
        ~A(){}
        int getNr(){ return this->number; }
        int number;
        operator int() { return getNr(); }
};

int main(int, char *[]) {
    A a(42);
    doSomething(a); // calls operator int() above
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful with user-defined conversion operators. In particular, it's often best to mark them `explicit` and use `static_cast<T>()` to trigger the conversion. Implicit conversions can quickly get you into trouble with overload resolution.